# Converting statements to propositional logic and conjunctive normal form (CNF)

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I have the following task:

> Defne the following statements in propositional logic:
>
> 1. The system heats if the cover is closed and the power is on.
> 2. If the lamp shines, the power is on.
> 3. The lamp shines.
> 4. The cover is closed.
>
> Rewrite above statements to conjunctive normal form and prove by contradiction and resolution that the system heats.

My propositional logic:

```
systemHeats → coverIsClosed ∧  powerIsOn
lampShines → powerIsOn
lampShines
coverIsClosed
```

My CNF:

```
(¬ systemHeats ∨ coverIsClosed) ∧ (¬ systemHeats ∨ powerIsOn)
¬ lampShines ∨ powerIsOn
lampShines
coverIsClosed
```

Is this correct?

I'm supposed to prove by contradiction and resolution that the system heats. Can you link me to an explanation on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not correct.  You need to revise the first premise.  "This *if* that" means $\textsf{that}\to\textsf{this}$.

To use resolution, you add an additional premise --the negation of the aledged conclusion-- aiming to derive a contradiction.

Thus your initial list should be:

```
(coverIsClosed ∧ powerIsOn) → systemHeats
lampShines → powerIsOn
lampShines
coverIsClosed
~systemHeats
```

Now, put these in CNF (which you've shown that you can do okay) and resolve.

Comment: do I have to put everything into CNF (namely line 1 and 2) or just line 1?

Comment: I'm stuck here: (¬ coverIsClosed ∧ ¬ powerIsOn) ∨ systemHeats

Comment: You have to use whichever rules you have been given to use, @HaiseSasaki .  But, yes, most likely. Edit: Also it is:$$\lnot\text{coverIsClosed}\lor\lnot\text{powerIsOn}\lor\text{systemHeats}$$ Recall: deMorgan's Rules.  $\lnot(A\land B)\equiv (\lnot A\lor\lnot B)$

Comment: that's those aren't "conjunctions of disjunctions" ? So I can't use resolution?

Comment: $P\lor Q\lor R$ is a conjunction of *one* disjunction of three literals.  It is in CNF